# Join two M:N relations in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, orm

Look at my model below,

1. Each user got n roles
2. Each role got n permissions / each permission got n roles

I'm trying to get user permissions to be able to execute a *group by* on it,
how could I do it?

[image: My data model]

I was going to write a LINQ query like below:

```
from uRole in context.Users.Single(u => u.Id == userId).Roles
     join p in context.Permission.Where(p => p.Type == ModelEnums.PermissionType.Module)
```

I don't know how to write the query, can anybody guide me?

Comment: So, why didn't you write & test the output of your querry and tell us the result/problem?

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to write the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the user's permissions you can use the [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method:

```
var permissions=context.Users.Single(u => u.Id == userId).Roles.SelectMany(r=>r.Permissions).Distinct();
```

Also call the [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method to remove duplicates.

Comment: As a newbie in EF I've never noticed that there is SelectMany!

You saved my week, I don't know how to say thank you :)